# Gradle Plugin Execution Order

Tags: gradle, flyway, jooq

I have written this gradle file

```
group 'com.abhi'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.flywaydb.flyway'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
        classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.7.1'
        classpath 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.177'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq', version: '3.7.1'
    compile group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-meta', version: '3.7.1'
    compile group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-codegen', version: '3.7.1'
    runtime group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.177'
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:h2:file:target/foobar'
    user = 'sa'
}

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
        .configuration('xmlns': 'http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.7.0.xsd') {
    jdbc() {
        driver('org.h2.Driver')
        url('dbc:h2:file:target/foobar')
        user('sa')
        password('')
    }
    generator() {
        database() {
        }
        generate() {
        }
        target() {
            packageName('com.abhi.jooq.models')
            directory('src/main/java')
        }
    }
}

// Run the code generator
// ----------------------
org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.generate(
        javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(writer.toString()), org.jooq.util.jaxb.Configuration.class)
)
```

when I say `gradle compile` it throws an exception

```
Could not load schemata
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl.meta(MetaImpl.java:120)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl.getCatalogs(MetaImpl.java:143)
    at org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl.getSchemas(MetaImpl.java:168)
    at org.jooq.util.jdbc.JDBCDatabase.getSchemasFromMeta(JDBCDatabase.java:135)
    at org.jooq.util.jdbc.JDBCDatabase.getSchemata0(JDBCDatabase.java:124)
    at org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase.getSchemata(AbstractDatabase.java:279)
```

I think the problem is that the code at the bottom of the script executes much before the "flyway" plugin.

Is there a way I can ensure that the code below is executed only after the flyway plugin has executed?

Comment: It looks as though your jOOQ codegeneration plugin wasn't properly configured with a connection. Could you show that configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you suppose, the problem is in execution order, then you can modify it, just like with any other tasks. Take a look at the documentation of the [flyway plugin](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/). According to it, this plugin adds some extra tasks to your build script, for thos one tasks are: `flywayMigrate`, `flywayClean` etc. You can make any of your tasks depending (with `dependsOn` option) on the tasks form this plugin and make them running just after the plugin's job is done.